# Refer to variables outside a function python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python function to find the sum of all nodes in a binary tree,simply by using inorder traversal, something like this:

```
sum=0
def tree_sum(root):
    if root!=None:
        tree_sum(root.left)
        sum=sum+root.data
        tree_sum(root.right)
```

I am getting the following error though:

```
sum=sum+root.data
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment
```

Is there a reason why I am not able to reference the variable sum in this case? I did similar stuff(referencing variables in such a fashion) in Jupyter notebooks and it works.

Comment: @enzo provided a thorough answer, but you might also want to read through [Python's scoping rules](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#:~:text=The%20LEGB%20rule%20is%20a,the%20first%20occurrence%20of%20it.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't name your variable `sum` because it'll shadow [the `sum` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). I'll replace it with `node_sum`.

Your first `node_sum` is being declared on the top level, thus it's a global variable. That said, you can't change a global variable without using the `global` keyword inside your function:

```
node_sum = 0

def tree_sum(root):
    # Allow the global `node_sum` to be mutated inside this function
    global node_sum

    if root != None:
        tree_sum(root.left)
        node_sum = node_sum + root.data
        tree_sum(root.right)
```

---

However, a better practice is to not have any global variables at all. Make your `tree_sum` function return the sum of the current tree, and add it to a local variable `node_sum`:

```py
def tree_sum(root):
    node_sum = 0

    if root != None:
        node_sum += tree_sum(root.left)
        node_sum += root.data
        node_sum += tree_sum(root.right)

    return node_sum
```

And then you can use it like

```
root = ...
print(tree_sum(root))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not a good idea to use the variable name as `sum`. coz, python has a built-in function for sum

Yet you can try like this:

```
sum=0
def tree_sum(root):
    global sum
    if root!=None:
        tree_sum(root.left)
        sum=sum+root.data
        tree_sum(root.right)
```

or try like this:

```
total=0
def tree_sum(root):
    global total
    if root!=None:
        tree_sum(root.left)
        total=total+root.data
        tree_sum(root.right)
```

or simply make it reusable making a return

```
def tree_sum(root):
    total = 0
    if root!=None:
        tree_sum(root.left)
        total=total+root.data
        tree_sum(root.right)
     return total
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to call a variable `sum` since that's a built-in function for Python

Comment: Why make the variable global? I would define `total=0` inside the function `tree_sum` in which case your answer is identical to the one provided by @enzo

Comment: @DerekO I have answered first.

Comment: Please read the question, coz, the guy already tried to mutate a global varaible

Comment: Here you go for the reason: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: There is no need to use a global variable at all if you simply return the total in the function `tree_sum` but I suppose if someone with a similar question for some reason needs the total to be defined outside of the scope of the function, then your answer would be appropriate.